# Выключи свет и выключай свет

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как правильно просить выключить свет "выключай свет" и "выключи свет". Что то подсказывает что "выключай свет" трактуется как приказ, "выключи свет" трактуется как просьба. Кроме того "выключай свет" все таки подходит для случаев, когда свет нужно выключать периодически, а не прямо сейчас. Как говорить правильно? Почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

"Выключай" - глагол в повелительном наклонении. Такие формы обозначают побуждение к действию (просьбу, совет, приказ, призыв, предупреждение, запрет). Здесь всё зависит от интонации, с которой произносится фраза. Можно приказать и фразой "Выключи свет!". А если добавить волшебное слово "пожалуйста", то и один и другой вариант будет восприниматься просьбой.

Comment: Выключай, пожалуйста свет... Как то не по русски вам не кажется? Если речь идет не о процессе, а о побуждении к немедленному действию

Comment: Вполне по-русски. Ребёнок сидит, читает книгу. Уже поздно. Пора спать. Заходит мама и говорит ему: "Выключай, пожалуйста, свет и ложись спать". Призыв к действию в вежливой форме.

Answer (score 2):

Если отставить в сторону вежливые добавки, эти варианты различаются ситуациями использования.

"**Выключи**" может использоваться в значении просьбы, приказа или требования, причём вне зависимости от предшествующей ситуации, *неожиданно*.

"**Выключай**" (помимо очевидных ситуаций многократного действия, напр. "уходя, выключай свет") может потребоваться в ситуации взаимодействия людей, договорившихся выключить свет в определённый момент (перед началом фильма, перед устраиванием "темной" кому-то в казарме, перед каким-либо экспериментом, требующим затемнения  и т.п.) или начинающих совместное действие, требующее от одного из них (кому это удобнее сделать) выключения света. Например:

> Ну всё, я готов (ко сну, включить кинопроектор, достать плёнку для
>   проявки и т.п.). Выключай свет.

Для такой ситуации характерно предполагаемое **ожидание** адресатом просьбы, команды или даже требования ("*а ну, выключай - сам знаешь, что мешаешь*").

Comment: Согласен. Только вы за особенностями очень скомкано суть изложили. Грамматический вид. а суть все-таки именно в многократности второго варианта.

Comment: В данном случае интерес представляет именно нетипичное, причём не просто корректное, а и предпочтительное использование глагола несовершенного вида повелительного наклонения в ряде характерных ситуаций. Поэтому вывести правильность выбора глагола из деления на совершенный и несовершенный вид здесь нельзя, как нельзя в принципе конструировать речь на родном языке из классифицированных грамматических конструкций - это чревато речевыми ошибками. Живой язык сложнее набора выводимых из него же правил.

Comment: *В данном случае интерес представляет именно нетипичное, причём не просто корректное*  - во-первых, это не так, у каждого свой интерес,  а во-вторых, каким бы не был интерес, основной случай все равно нельзя замалчивать, ибо не всем же понятно, что вы это из-=за своего интереса скомкали изложение.

Comment: Да, у каждого свой интерес, но у задавшего вопрос этот интерес конкретный - как правильно говорить в той или иной ситуации. Выводить ответ из классификации глаголов в этом конкретном случае бесполезно, в частности, утверждение о том, что "главным образом этим передаётся многократность" даже вредно для понимания того, как следует говорить в часто встречающихся ситуациях - здесь важен ситуационный аспект употребления глагола, а вовсе не терминологический.

Answer (score 0):

Воспринимается и то и другое как приказ или как наставление в зависимости от ситуации. Грамматически тут нет и не может быть разделения, поскольку и то и другое - повеоительное наклонение.

Выключи (от выключить) - глагол совершенного вида, может означать однократное действие, но не строго, может по контексту восприниматься и как многократное.

Выключай (от выключать) - несовершенного вида, используется главным образом для передачи многократности, и вообще и особенно - в повелительной форме.